# How to get only the results of 'knife search' commands

Tags: chef-infra, knife

When we run **knife search** command, it is listing the number of items found. I don't want the number of items, instead i need only the results. How to get it.
Example to say, I would like to get some return code or nil value for the below command.

```
$ knife search node "name:MyLinux AND role:java"
0 items found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use [knife exec](http://docs.chef.io/knife_exec.html) for this and use the `exit`method of ruby.

Example (even if it's try to undertand what you wish to accomplish with so few details/context):

```
knife exec -E "exit nodes.find('name:MyLinux AND role:java').count > 0"; echo $?
```

Which will return 0 if nothing is found and 1 if any number of nodes are found.

If you wish to do something to the nodes (like adding a recipe to the run_list):

```
knife exec -E "nodes.find('name:MyLinux AND role:java') { |n| n.run_list << 'cookbook::recipe'; n.save }"
```

Comment: @amhser you may consider accepting (the tick sign) the answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 3):

The "X items found" is written to `stderr`, so it might be easier to just redirect it:

```
$ knife search node "name:MyLinux AND role:java" 2> /dev/null
```